# UIStackview with differently aligned subviews

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, uistackview

I'd like to align the Blue and Purple views to the center of the screen, and I'd like to align the green view to the left of the screen:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

//Stackview: 
let stackView   = UIStackView()
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(stackView)

stackView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.topAnchor).active = true
stackView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leftAnchor).active = true
stackView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.rightAnchor).active = true

stackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical
stackView.alignment = .Center

//Blue view: 
let blueBox = UIView()
stackView.addArrangedSubview(blueBox)
blueBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
blueBox.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(140).active = true
blueBox.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(140).active = true

//Inner stackview that contains the green view: 
let greenBoxContainer = UIStackView()
let greenBox = UIView()
stackView.addArrangedSubview(greenBoxContainer)
greenBoxContainer.addArrangedSubview(greenBox)
greenBoxContainer.alignment = .Leading

//Green view:
greenBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
greenBox.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(120).active = true
greenBox.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(120).active = true

//Purple view: 
let purpleView = UIView()
stackView.addArrangedSubview(purpleView)
purpleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
purpleView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50.0).active = true
purpleView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50.0).active = true
```

To repeat, how can I align the left edge of the green view with the left edge of the screen?

I tried this:

```
greenBoxContainer.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(stackView.widthAnchor).active = true
```

but it only stretches the green view through the length of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add a spacer view:

```
let greenBox = UIView()
stackView.addArrangedSubview(greenBoxContainer)
greenBoxContainer.addArrangedSubview(greenBox)

let spacer = UIView()
greenBoxContainer.addArrangedSubview(spacer)
spacer.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(greenBoxContainer.rightAnchor).active = true

greenBoxContainer.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(stackView.widthAnchor).active = true
greenBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
greenBox.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(120).active = true
greenBox.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(120).active = true
```

Note that I'm no longer setting `greenBoxContainer`'s alignment, so it defaults to `.Fill`. Thus the right edge of `spacer` is flushed to the inner stackview's right edge, and it takes up all the width, leaving `greenBox` just enough room to satisfy its width constraint.

But this is a workaround, I'd like to be able to specify alignments without having to create spacer views..